# Windows store app fails AppContainerCheck

Tags: c#, xaml, compiler-construction, linker, windows-store-apps

I'm getting the below error when I try to run the app certification test on my windows 8.1 app. I've looked around for a while and can't seem to find any solutions for this. The app is written in C#/xaml which I wasn't aware even had a linker.

I'm hoping that someone can guide me in the right direction on how I should start to investigate an error like this as web searches have thus far failed me

Binary analyzer

•Error Found: The binary analyzer test detected the following errors:
◦File [MyTabletApplication.exe] has failed the AppContainerCheck check.

•Impact if not fixed: If the app doesn’t use the available Windows protections, it can increase the vulnerability of the customer's computer to malware.

•How to fix: Apply the required linker options - SAFESEH, DYNAMICBASE, NXCOMPAT, and APPCONTAINER - when you link the app. See links below for more information:

Comment: Hi @JacobDuval, Were you able to fix this issue? I am hitting the same error with my app. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything useful on the web yet.

Comment: Hey man, I couldn't find a good solution but from memory we ended up not needing the windows store in the end anyway. If you find the answer please come back here and post it!

Comment: Hi @JacobDuval, Thanks for the response. I was able to solve this issue for my WIndows-10 Desktop app. For x86 platform I had to link with -SAFESEH & -APPCONTAINER and for x64 platform -APPCONTAINER

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 and this is a new solution/project make sure the 'Compile with .NET Native tool chain' check box is cleared in the startup project properties in the Release configuration.

Comment: As far as I know .NET Native it's not a requirement for the store right and you should be able to upload a package without the .Net Native if you require so. I'm having the same problems with a Windows 10 App.

Comment: this was an old question regarding Windows Store Apps on Windows 8/8.1 when .NET Native wasn't generally available...now with Windows Store apps on W10 (Windows Universal Apps) .NET Native is enabled by default on Release builds and clearly the certification passes. About if .Net Native is a requirement I'm quite sure that even if you upload a package not compiled with .Net Native to the Store it will be recompiled in the cloud. Apps are not running managed code anymore on W10 and W10M they're all compiled to machine code. If you are having problems look somewhere else for an answer.